# How to use Equivalence.wrap() to dedupe a Set?

Tags: java, guava

I must be missing something about `Equivalence.wrap()` but the following test fails for me - using guava 18.0 at the very last line only. Why? What am I doing wrong? My aim is to deduplicate equivalent objects by adding them to a set.

```
    @Test
    public void testEquivalenceWrap()
    {
        final Equivalence<Program2> eq = EquivalentIfIDsEven.INSTANCE;

        Program2 p1 = new Program2();
        p1.setId(2L);

        Program2 p2 = new Program2();
        p2.setId(4L);


        //sanity-test equivalence impl
        assertFalse(p1.equals(p2));
        assertTrue(eq.equivalent(p1, p2));
        assertTrue(eq.wrap(p1).equals(eq.wrap(p2)));

        //dedupe in set
        final Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<Program2>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(eq.wrap(p1));
        set.add(eq.wrap(p2));

        assertEquals(1, set.size()); //FAIL: size == 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd get this behavior if your `Equivalence` doesn't implement hashing correctly.  Without seeing more code, I can't suggest something more specific, but that's almost certainly what's happening.

Comment: You're correct! My `Equivalence.doHash()` impl didn't satisfy the distributable property. I.e. `doHash(p1) != doHash(p2)` - incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I try to use this class (example EqualsEquivalence from javadoc in Equivalent class) in you test:

```
static final class EquivalentIfIDsEven extends Equivalence<Program2>
        implements Serializable {

    static final EquivalentIfIDsEven INSTANCE = new EquivalentIfIDsEven();

    @Override protected boolean doEquivalent(Program2 a, Program2 b) {
        return a.equals(b);
    }
    @Override protected int doHash(Program2 o) {
        return o.hashCode();
    }

    private Program2 readResolve() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
}
```